# Unpack a pickle variable without a file?

Tags: python, pickle

I pickled a python variable without opening a file using this code below, but I can't seem to unpack it without a file.

```
import pickle

class Foo:
   attr = 'a class attr'

picklestring = pickle.dumps(Foo)

print(picklestring)
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to try to unpack the string.

Comment: have you tried `pickle.loads`?

Comment: ...how in the world do you know about `pickle.dumps` but not `pickle.loads`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I accidentally used .load and not .loads. I just started out using pickle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unpickle from a bytes object, use [`pickle.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads):

```
In [3]: import pickle
   ...:
   ...: class Foo:
   ...:    attr = 'a class attr'
   ...:
   ...: picklestring = pickle.dumps(Foo)
   ...:
   ...: print(picklestring)
   ...:
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nFoo\nq\x00.'

In [4]: pickle.loads(picklestring)
Out[4]: __main__.Foo
```